# ConTeXt: Insert web site hyperlink

Tags: hyperref, context, links

I need the analogue of latex's `\href` in context. I need a link when clicking on which pdf viewer would open a browser with it's url.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a basic usage for [URLs](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/URL):

```
\definecolor[HyperlinkExternal][h=2F66B1]

\setupinteraction[
  state=start,
  color=HyperlinkExternal,
]

\startasciimode
  \useURL
    [search]
    [https://www.google.com/search?q=context%20tex%20urls]
    []
    [\ConTeXt search]
\stopasciimode

\starttext
  Perform a \from[search] for URLs.
\stoptext
```

This approach is more flexible than `\goto{name}[url(http://link.com)]` as all hyperlinks can be defined in a single location. It also simplifies escaping.